# Hierarchy in Packages

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I'm doing simulations of optical properties and started to create a package for my own use that includes all functions and object I have written so far.
For obvious reasons I use numpy and I used to `import numpy` in my modules.

Now, with the package, I wish to make numpy globally available for every submodule. From what I've gathered so far, this might be bad practice. However, if I `import numpy` in each module I get numpy as a key/function for that module, which seems to be even worse practice.

In other words:
When I create a minimal package with only `package/__init __.py` and `package/module.py` and `import numpy` in `module.py`, import it and print all available functions

```
import package
print package.module.__dict__.keys()
['__builtins__', '__file__', '__package__', 'numpy', '__name__', '__doc__']
```

numpy shows up.
So in principle I could access numpy via

```
package.module.numpy
```

I am not sure if this is really a problem and how this is done correctly.

Comment: It's not really a problem. The standard modules do it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Sneftel's comment -- this isn't a problem.

Since this is not part of the documented interface of your module, although the user can see there is *something named numpy* in the module (which is not necessarily the numpy module, it could be anything), as a grownup, the user should avoid using it.

Comment: Hah, that gives me a great idea. `import numpy as _calibrationNode`. `import os.path as numpy`. *Keep them guessing.*

Comment: @Sneftel ... we're all supposed to be responsible grown ups! ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad to be a responsible adult. I just expected to work differently.